# Terraform EC2 User Data Changes Not Replacing The EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, user-data

I've noticed recently Terraform or AWS has made a change EC2 userdata so that changes don't trigger a 'replace' in terraform.
Quote Terraform [aws_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#user_data) docs: *Updates to this field will trigger a stop/start of the EC2 instance.*

We have automated deployments that rely on userdata changes to trigger replacements, so that the new userdata is ran everytime.

Is there a way Terraform can be told to replace instances is it notices new userdata?
Lambda has a similar issue that is solved with 'source_code_hash'
Is there something similar I can use here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Good news, terraform-provider-aws has an open issue ticket where many are reporting this issue. Feedback from individuals who rely on user_data to initiate a replace on their EC2 instances have been reported. This includes CI/CD pipelines that are now broken.

jaredholgate mentions they are planning to add a parameter called *user_data_replace_on_change* - it will be false by default.

In the meantime, you can use the -replace flag to target your ec2 instance. For example:

```html
terraform plan -replace aws_instance.my_ec2_instance
terraform apply -replace aws_instance.my_ec2_instance
```

For citation purposes, this issue has been reported at: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23315

Comment: has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The change has come from within a new Terraform AWS provider [version](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23315)

If you are running userdata with [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html) an easy fix would be to use the cloud-init type x-shellscript-per-boot instead of x-shellscript.

This would mean any userdata updates would be ran every stop/start.